# Pointer arithmetic: By how much is y increased?

Tags: c, pointers, reference, dereference

I'm struggling with this  pointer arithmetic:

```
int x;
int *y = &x;
++y;
```

By how much is y increased?

I know that:
"`&`" is the reference operator and can be read as “address of”.
"`*`" is the dereference operator and can be read as “value pointed by”.

But I don't quite understand how this works.
Is it right that y contains the address of x, *y shows the value of x?

Is y increased by 1? (if x = 4 =>> `++y` = 1 + 4 = 5)
or by 4? (because of Type "int" ? =>>  `++y` = 4 + 4 = 9)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Address arithmetic in C is in units of the type of the pointer operated on. so `++` for an `int` will add `sizeof(int)` bytes and for a char it adds `sizeof(char)` (is 1) bytes.

Comment: The value of `x` is irrelevant because you are operating on its address.

Answer (score 3):

1. `*y` will dereference value of `x`
2. ++y will reference the next int object. But because you have only allocated the space for one (defining the `x` object) the result of dereference is undefined.
3. ```
   int x[2] = {1,2};
   int *y = &x[0];

   printf("%d\n, *y);
   y++;
   printf("%d\n, *y);
   ```

will print

`1
 2`